# How do I use an AND statement in XPATH?

Tags: xpath

I have this query `//*[@id="test"]/div/[not(contains(.,'/explore'))]`

I want to add a second 'not contains' command to this:

```
//*[@id="test"]/div/[not(contains(.,'/locations'))]
```

And maybe even a 3rd one. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of what you posted is a valid XPath expression. If you meant to filter the `div` element so that only `div` that doesn't contain certain string, say `"/explore"`, is returned, you can do this way instead :

```
//*[@id="test"]/div[not(contains(.,'/explore'))]
```

and another XPath example that check if the `div` doesn't contain any of 2 strings, `"/explore"` and `"/locations"` :

```
//*[@id="test"]/div[not(contains(.,'/explore')) and not(contains(.,'/locations'))]
```